# Do TCP Sockets require a wired connection?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I am reading about TCP sockets which require a connection to be set up between a client and a server. Is it possible to have TCP sockets working on a wireless connection?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? Why do you think LAN and wired are the same thing?

Comment: I am just saying wired connection not wireless .

Comment: Have you ever seen someone using the web on a laptop or a smart phone but without a wired network connection? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are interpreting 'connection' to mean 'physical link' (as in, wires). This is incorrect.

'physical' in networking extends to all data transfer mediums. In the case of wireless, this is the radio waves. In terms of TCP a 'connection' is made when one computer is listening on a network and responds to a second computer who makes a request.

TCP doesn't care what physical medium it is travelling through.

With regards to your question it may help to think of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). In this model TCP sits at level 4. What this should mean is that it can be mostly oblivious to what happens above and below it.

The actual physical layer is level 1 of the OSI model, so TCP should not have to care what is happening there. Thus, whether you are using wires, wireless, fiber or pieces of paper to send the TCP packets is irrelevant, so long as the protocol is enacted as described.

Comment: And if using pieces of paper, consult RFC 1149: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - Yes.

Read more at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Comment: Where it mentioned in this wiki page??

Comment: This is about TCP in general, but specifically here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_over_wireless_networks

Comment: Thanks @MByD but what the meaning of establish connection between client and Server machine??

Comment: If you want to talk to communicate the someone over TCP/IP, he needs to listen. In such case you are the client and he is the server.

Answer (score 0):

I hope so - I am using mobile broadband. And web access uses TCP/Sockets.

Comment: The question was about wireless connections - mobile  broadband is wireless.

Answer (score 0):

The network technology is organized in so called [layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Physical transmission of signals is responsibility of the first layer. It can be copper cable, optical fiber, radio signals, [homing pigeons](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt), whatever technology there is to get zeros and ones between the machines.

TCP is a fourth layer protocol. It relies on the bottom three layers to route packets of data from the source to the destination. It's responsibility is to make sure that the packets arrive in an orderly fashion.

The whole point of this layered structure is that when you program networking drivers, you don't need to worry what kind of data the user will send on the network. When you program web application you don't need to worry if the user is connected with an ethernet CAT-5 cable, or a cable TV modem.